# C# Show another form in a loop

Tags: c#, loops, asynchronous, async-await

So I'm trying to do a program which shows an alert for every number that called. I'm doing webscraping to my router in order to obtain the numbers which are called. The thing is;

```
while (true)
{
   Thread.Sleep(5000);
   if (!numbers.SequenceEqual(getNumber()))
   {
     numbers = getNumber();

     alert alert = new alert();
     alert.setAlert(numbers.First());
     //break;
   }
}
```

I'm using a while which is constantly every 5sec check if someone called. And because of that when I show the alert (which is just another form) it doesn't show properly. I just did the test using break, and it works so that's why I assumed it's because the loop. I know little to nothing about async method, and I think this could be a solution...?

Thanks and sorry for my bad english!

### Update with the whole code;

Form1.Shown

---

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
   service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   options.AddArgument("headless");

   ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
   driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://192.168.0.1/");

   var user = driver.FindElementByName("loginUsername");
   var pass = driver.FindElementByName("loginPassword");
   var submit = driver.FindElementByClassName("Login-button");

   user.SendKeys("blablabla");
   pass.SendKeys("blablabla");
   submit.Click();

   List<string> getNumber()
   {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://192.168.0.1/CallLog.asp");

        var botonPerdidas = driver.FindElementByCssSelector("li[class='TabbedPanelsTab kR']");
        botonPerdidas.Click();

        List<string> strNumbers = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 2; i < 20; i++)
        {
          try
          {
             strNumbers.Add(driver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/form/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div[" + i + "]/div[4]").Text);
          }
          catch (Exception)
          {
             break;
          }
        }
         return strNumbers;
   }


   List<string> numbers = getNumber();

   while (true)
   {
      Thread.Sleep(5000);
      if (!numbers.SequenceEqual(getNumber()))
      {
         numbers = getNumber();

         alert alert = new alert();
         alert.setAlert(numbers.First());
      }
   }

}
```

The follow method is in the alert form, which is invoked from form1 in the loop for every time I detect a new call.

Alert.setAlert

---

```
public void setAlert(string msg)
{

    this.Text = msg;
    this.Opacity = 0.0;
    this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    string fname;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
       fname = "alert" + i.ToString();
       alert f = (alert)Application.OpenForms[fname];

       if (f == null)
       {
         this.Name = fname;
         this.x = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - this.Width + 15;
         this.y = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - this.Height * i - 5 * i;
         this.Location = new Point(this.x, this.y);
         break;
       }

    }

        this.x = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - base.Width - 5;
        this.label1.Text = msg;
        this.Show();
}
```

### Trying to move it out from the form level.

[image]

ErrorMessage: It doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: Is this loop executed in the main thread?

Comment: In the form load event @Ralf

Comment: If that is winforms move the code into the shown event. Load is a in between situation for a form. Its somewhere between showing and not showing. Opening some other form from there can lead to all kinds of problems.

Comment: I just tried it, but it happens the same. The second form is showed in the taskbar but it doesn't appear as a popup also it seems like it didn't load at all, it seems it just load if I scape from the loop. Gonna update with the whole code, maybe it can be helpful @Ralf

Comment: Get rid of the `while` loop.  Drop a `Timer` on your form and set its `Interval` property to 5000.  Put your `if` statement in the `Tick` event...

Comment: @Idle_Mind At first I thought in that, but I need the var driver inside my timer and it seems I can't put the var driver as a global one, that's why I did that with while. Any idea?

Comment: Why can't you make `driver` "global" (move it out to Form level)?

Comment: Other options might be to use the `Aync`/`Await` model.

Comment: @Idle_Mind To be honest, I'm pretty sure it's because I don't know how to do it. When I move the `ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);` out of the form level, it asks me for the service and options, so I tried also to move the `service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;` and the rest of the code out of the move, but visual tell me it doesn´t exist in the current context. I will update with a picture, so maybe it can be show clearly. (Also I'm really sorry for my bad english.)

Comment: Right...you'd DECLARE it at Form level, but leave the `new` part in the `Shown()` event.

Comment: you main issue is your while loop is on your main thread aka the thread which is handling .... form views... , any interaction, that thread is being held permanently. You need to look into ways of off loading.... your loop into another thread so the ui (main) thread can continue to flow like normal.

Comment: @Idle_Mind god, I swear that I'm so stupid, it works, thanks!

Comment: Yay!  Glad you figured it out my friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably due to the following rules in windows forms:

1. You shall not block the UI(main) thread with long running operations
2. You shall only update ui elements from the UI thread

Running an infinite loop in the `Show()` event breaks rule #1 and will cause issues.

Make your driver a field in the form an instantiate this in the constructor (or show event if needed) and create a regular [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=netcore-3.1) that executes ever 5s:

```
ChromeDriverService service;
Timer myTimer;
public Form1(){
    InitializeComponent() 
    service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
    ...
    myTimer = new Timer();
    myTimer.Tick += TimerEventProcessor; 
    myTimer.Interval = 5000;
    myTimer.Start();
    ...
}
```

Create the event handler method to handle the event:

```
private TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs) {
   
  if (!numbers.SequenceEqual(getNumber()))
  {
     numbers = getNumber();
     alert alert = new alert();
     alert.setAlert(numbers.First());
  }
}
```

Comment: It was the `ChromeDriver` which I needed to move it out from the form, but now it works perfectly. Thanks!